# Is it possible to make css flexbox be responsive when background is repetitive?

Tags: css, flexbox

I created [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8y14m7zo/10/) There's an example of my question.

```
<div>
 <span class="side"></span>
 <span class="middle"></span>
 <span class="side"></span>
</div>
```

I want to create a footer which consists from 3 parts(1 - image in the middle, 2 and 3 - repetitive image on left and right side  ). 
The problem in my case it’s not responsive. As you can see on screenshot it has additional space between.
I tried to apply flex-shrink for **.side** but no luck. 
[image]

Comment: for the middle use the image as img tag not background .. and remove the width:100% then add `flex:1` to both sides

Comment: You could just have a repeating image and then put a white background on your text then you don't need the side bits

Comment: Thanks, it helps.